# discord.js list all my bot commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, bots, discord.js

i made a discord bot with discord.js and tried to do a help command to show the user all available commands.

example command: *avatar.js*

```
module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args) => {
    let msg = await message.channel.send("doing some magic ...");
    let target = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;

    await message.channel.send({files: [
        {
            attachment: target.displayAvatarURL,
            name: "avatar.png"
        }
    ]});

    msg.delete();
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "avatar",
    description: "show the avatar of a user",
    usage: "[@user]"
}
```

Then i tried to send a message with the complete list of the commands like:

- **command 1**
- description
- usage
- **command 2**
- description
- usage
- ...

*help.js*

```
const fs = require("fs");
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args, con) => {
    fs.readdir("./cmds/", (err, files) => {
        if(err) console.error(err);

        let jsfiles = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");
        if(jsfiles.length <= 0) {
            console.log("No commands to load!");
            return;
        }

        var namelist = "";
        var desclist = "";
        var usage = "";

        let result = jsfiles.forEach((f, i) => {
            let props = require(`./${f}`);
            namelist = props.help.name;
            desclist = props.help.description;
            usage = props.help.usage;
        });

        message.author.send(`**${namelist}** \n${desclist} \n${usage}`);
    });
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "help",
    description: "show all commands",
    usage: ""
}
```

my code is kinda working but it only sends the first command.

Im pretty new to javascript and i can't find a solution to this.
I tried to google everything on foreach maps discord collections and stuff but i cant find a example where the results get combined together.

If anybody can help me or give me a hint where i can search for something like this. Would be awesome.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your code is only sending the one command is because your code only calls `message.author.send('...'` once. You successfully set the variables `namelist`, `desclist`, and `usage` with data from every file, but your `.forEach(...` loop just overwrites all of the data when it moves to the next files.

Try to send data inside each iteration of the `.forEach(...` loop like this:

```
var namelist = "";
var desclist = "";
var usage = "";

let result = jsfiles.forEach((f, i) => {
    let props = require(`./${f}`);
    namelist = props.help.name;
    desclist = props.help.description;
    usage = props.help.usage;

    // send help text
    message.author.send(`**${namelist}** \n${desclist} \n${usage}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you should do this in an Array and it'll solve the problem, so it should look like this.

```js
module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args, con) => {
    fs.readdir("./cmds/", (err, files) => {
        if(err) console.error(err);

        let jsfiles = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");
        if(jsfiles.length <= 0) {
            console.log("No commands to load!");
            return;
        }


        let result = jsfiles.forEach((f, i) => {
            let props = require(`./${f}`);
            let filesArray = [props.help.name, props.help.description, props.help.usage]
            message.author.send(`**${filesArray[0]}** \n${filesArray[1]} \n${filesArray[2]}`);
        });

    });
}
```

sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on this.... it works for me.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js'); 
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = {
    name: 'help',
    description: 'Lists available commands',

    async run(client, message, args, con) {
        fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {
            if(err) console.error(err);
    
            let jsfiles = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");
            if(jsfiles.length <= 0) {
                console.log("No commands to load!");
                return;
            }
            
            var namelist = "";
            var desclist = "";
            
            let result = jsfiles.forEach((f, i) => {
                let props = require(`./${f}`);
                namelist = props.name;
                desclist = props.description;
                message.author.send(`**${namelist}** \n${desclist} \n`);
            });
     

     
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using DiscordJS 12 so this may not work on 11.

```
const discord = require('discord.js')
module.exports = {
name: 'cmd-list',
async run(client, message, args) {
const commandFiles = readdirSync(join(__dirname, "<your commands folder name>")).filter(file => file.endsWith(".js")); // Get files
const cmdmap = commandFiles.map(files => `${files}`).join(' | Working\n')
const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
.setDescription(cmdmap)
message.channel.send(embed)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use discord 's normal embed system like this:

```
const { Message, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
```

Add this to the top of your code then type everything as the following to make a normal embed like this:

```
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
     .setTitle(`Your title!`)
     .setColor(5814783)
     .setTimestamp()
     .setThumbnail('')
     .setDescription(`Your description`)
     .addFields(
     { name: 'Field 1', value: `Filed 1 Value`},
     { name: 'Field 2', value: `Filed 2 Value` },
     { name: 'Field 3', value: `Filed 3 Value`, inline: true },
     { name: 'Field 4', value: `Filed 4 Value`, inline: true },
     { name: 'Field 5', value: `Field 5 Value`, inline: true },
     )
message.channel.send(embed2)
```